# Optimise poorly performing T-SQL CASE expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, query-optimization

**UPDATE**

I've made a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fWgTmd71) with all relevant tables, indices and the entire MERGE (with edits to column names and such), since this was requested by a few people. I've also changed the CASE-expression from the original part of the question to reflect the fiddle's column names.

As mentioned, the MERGE isn't really the problem. The MERGE runs just fine (in a few seconds) when I remove the CASE-expression for populating the [Approved] column.

**Original question below**

I have a MERGE statement, that consolidates data from a few different tables. I recently moved this solution to a new server and the performance has severely degraded. On the old server, the statement would run in about 1.5 minute, but on the new server it takes over 25 minutes.

I've tried looking at execution plans and it seems the main perpetrator is a Table Spool (Lazy Spool). Running the MERGE on the new server with `OPTION (NO_PERFORMANCE_SPOOL)` takes the runtime down to about 17.5 minutes.
I unfortunately have no influence over the settings or hardware of the new server and keeping the solution on the old server is not an option, so I've run out of ideas on this front.

Most of the MERGE is pretty simple, but I do have one field, populated according to a CASE expression:

```
CASE
  WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[Approved_Items] 
    WHERE [ID] IN (
      SELECT [OtherId] 
      FROM (
        SELECT [Source].[OtherId]
        UNION
        SELECT [Source].[Parent.OtherId] AS [OtherId]
        UNION
        SELECT [OtherId] FROM [dbo].[Child_Items] WHERE [Parent.Id] = [Source].[Id]
      ) AS S
      WHERE [OtherId] IS NOT NULL
    )
  ) THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

This is definitely the toughest part of the MERGE, since running it without this CASE expression takes the runtime down to 8 seconds. The logic is, if the Item's own ID, the ID of it's parent or the IDs of any of it's children appear in [dbo].[Approved_Items], this field is set to 1, else 0.

I'm sure this is far from the most optimal way to perform this logic, but unfortunately I'm not well-versed enough in T-SQL (SQL Server) to identify a better option.

Comment: A SQL fragment if of little use, can you show the full statement. It would probably be better to refactor the query to not use merge at all but a traditional upsert pattern, merge has [many known issues](https://sqlblog.org/merge) and is best avoided.

Comment: Please show the full `MERGE` statement, along with tables and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: I'm guessing it's probably more efficient to just do `CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Approved_Items ai WHERE ai.ID IN (Source.Id, Source.[Parent.Id]) OR ai.ID IN (SELECT ci.Id FROM dbo.Child_Items ci WHERE ci.[Parent.Id] = Source.Id) ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` but it's hard to say without having anything to test it on.

Comment: Try to write the result of the three union tables to a temp table and use it in the statement... Maybe this will help

Comment: @jigga Do you have suggestions on how to do this? As the result on the UNIONs depends on the current row being processed by the MERGE, I'm afraid I don't know enough to figure out how to do so efficiently.

Comment: Another idea: all of your Ids are nvarchar(255) but the values are int... Is this intentional?

Comment: So before your MERGE statement: ```SELECT [OtherId] INTO #tempIds FROM Items UNION SELECT [Parent.Id] FROM Child_Items UNION SELECT CI.[OtherId] FROM [dbo].[Child_Items] AS CI INNER JOIN Items AS I ON CI.[Parent.Id] = I.[Id];``` In the MERGE statement: ```CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Approved_Items] WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT [OtherId] FROM #tempIds WHERE [OtherId] IS NOT NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;```